# Login, Register problem in laravel 8 Cpanel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

The route is `https://test.iqbal.live/api/auth/login/`
field: **username** , **password**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVZ2H.png)

In local environment its fine, when i upload it cpanel give the error below:

```
{
  "message": "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.",
  "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
}
```

Comment: Show your headers, make sure you have `Content-Type: application/json` header set.

Comment: I already set this

Comment: you might have used get with browser .. try with postman or curl and use post

Comment: Could you please post your web.php routes as [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Try with postman ... its working...

[image]